# Way to rewrite Lists with multiple duplicates

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list

Having difficulty creating a short and clean list of items that contains several duplicates.
As an example, I have a list that contains all the cards of a deck. I need to be able to manipulate each item(the cards) without having to write each one out in the list.

Attempted to create lists that concatenate strings and integers but obviously that did not work well.

I would like a list similar to this:

```
 myList = [item1(6), item2(5), item3(4)]
```

I should be able to continue to draw from it as if it were written as such:

```
 myList = [item1, item1, item1, item1, item1, item1, item2, item2, item2, item2, item2...]
```

...you get the picture. I just do not want to write these long lists.

Expect a more organized list of multiple duplicating objects(Products in a store, Cards in a deck) but only come up with extremely long lists, irrelevant information, or errors.

Comment: Then just iterate through your list and create an array with the item name and the count of each.

Comment: @JGreenwell Not a duplicate, this question is not about counting

Comment: @DeepSpace your right I misread it - this just needs a standard dictionary of lists or even a class or a list of generators or your unpacking trick (I would assume the first two as I don't see how an unpack like that would be maintainable or easier to use after the assignment over a standard dictionary though it certainly answers the question)

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this contrived example if `item` is from the same class:

```
from copy import deepcopy

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __call__(self, n):
        return [deepcopy(self) for _ in range(n)]

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name


item1 = Foo('item1')
item2 = Foo('item2')
li = [item1(3), item2(2)]
print(li)
```

Outputs

```
[[item1, item1, item1], [item2, item2]]
```

With the downside of `li` ending up as a list of lists, which can be fixed with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

print(list(chain.from_iterable(li)))
```

Will output

```
[item1, item1, item1, item2, item2]
```

If you don't actually need each item to be a copy the implemenataion of `__call__` can be simplified to `return [self] * n`.

Another solution without needing `itertools.chain` exists if you allow the usage of `*` to unpack while creating `li`:

```
li = [*item1(3), *item2(2)]
print(li)
```

Will output

```
[item1, item1, item1, item2, item2]
```